# Translating an instruction sequence into a diagram

Tags: loops, assembly, optimization, diagram

Hello you guys I did a diagram of the instruction sequence and how it would be decoded into operations.  I also showed how the data dependencies between them would create a critical path of operations. My only question is simply if I did this correctly, i was confused at how to find %rbx as well. Please ask me any question you may have over my diagram, right now it is a rough draft. Thank you for your time.

```
.L15: # loop:

vmovsd 0(%rbp,%rcx,8), %xmm1 
vmulsd (%rax,%rcx,8), %xmm1, %xmm1 
vaddsd %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm0 
addq $1, %rcx 
cmpq %rbx, %rcx 
jl .L15 # If <, goto loop
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't there be an arrow from the left `Load` to the top `%xmm1`?

Comment: should there be only one load?

Comment: @Luke12: the code has two instructions with memory source operands, so there are two loads.  Also, you should distinguish integer `add` from FP `addsd` and `mulsd`.  Jester's right, xmm0 and xmm1 should be coming from the loads.  BTW, IACA can generate diagrams like this for you.  (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer, freeware from Intel, works on Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW, [IACA](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer) can generate diagrams like this for you.  It's closed-source freeware from Intel, and works on Linux.

---

You should distinguish integer `add` from FP `addsd` and `mulsd`.

Jester's right, xmm1 should be coming from the `vmovsd` load.

`vaddsd` writes xmm0.  You're using AT&T syntax, so the destination is the last operand.  Your diagram shows it modifying xmm1, but xmm0 is actually the accumulator.

---

`add` modifies `rcx`, but your diagram doesn't reflect that.  The dependency chain involving rcx is what forms the loop, so an arrow going back upwards would make sense there.

Like for `xmm0`, the arrows should form a cycle (closed loop).

---

re: your comment: The code has two instructions with memory source operands, so there are two loads.

Comment: @Luke12: it might be correct now, but it's nearly unreadable.  For registers that don't change in the loop, you don't need to list them twice.